# Why are my Firefox control buttons disappearing?

Tags: unity, firefox, launcher

Not sure if this is a "fault" or just me. The window control buttons (top left) in Firefox disappear behind the unity launch bar on the left of the screen when Firefox is maximised.

It is then impossible to resize the window as there are no controls.  ALT TAB and ALT F4 provide workarounds but are hardly convenient.  Is this issue "normal" or am I missing something?

This is my second day with Ubuntu / Unity.  (Loving it!!!!!)

Comment: Try double-clicking on Firefox's title bar.

Comment: can you post a screenshot? Press `PrtScr`/`Printscreen` button and edit the post to include it

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't Disappears , it just Looses focus .

Like here in **Top-Left Corner** , when Mouse is not hovering over it

[image]

And when you browse your mouse over it , it is **visible**.

[image]

You just have to **Double-Click** on the **Empty space** in the **Top-panel right to Firefox-title** or any other **Maximized window**  to Resize in older always.

Comment: Oh - now I feel so stupid.  Why did I not spot this?  Many thanks and sorry for wasting your time with a dumb question.

Comment: No problem , new Interface tends to makes us Stupid, but at the end of the day its makes learn its Simplicity . Do accept this as answer , if this solved your problem.

Comment: [how can you accept my answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/63025) which says tick mark the CORRECT circle Button , left to my answer. THANKS.